# How to control the video buffering

Tags: networking, internet, video-streaming

I have internet speed with 100 mbps with data usage of 30 GB.

Problem: Since my speed is high, video gets streamed completely. But I won't watch the complete video, I just watch few technical tips and close. So my data gets wasted. Is there anyway where we can could control the streaming manually?

**Actual Problem with brief description:**

I'm going through a technical class on adobe flash player. I' viewing it online, this video is about 4 hours but actual class is only for 3 hours. Remaining one hour video is just a ideal screen. So, problem is ,if i'm viewing the video for 3 hours, full 4 hours video gets buffered. **I want to control this video buffering manually**. Is it possible? I tried googling, but it say there is no possible solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using google chrome or chrome based browser right click anywhere in the page and click inspect element or (Control + Shift + I) if on windows, the click the "network" tab, change the no throttling option to the speed of your choice...

Am sure you will be fine as long as the **DevTools** are open. you will find similar option on other browsers.